# How can I use page parameter in a display:table tag

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, displaytag

In my controller, I fill a list in the property "items" and I render the list.jsp.

**list.jsp**

```
<jsp:include page="_list.jsp">
    <jsp:param value="${items}" name="items"/>
</jsp:include>
```

**_list.jsp**

```
<display:table name="${param.items}">               
    <display:column property="code" sortable="true"/>               
</display:table>
```

Nothing found/display! But when I write:

```
param.items = ${param.items}
```

I see the all items present in the list!
How can I use page's parameter in the display table tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try `<display:table name="items">`